# Stopping Quartz job created using MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, quartz

i create a job running a Spring bean class with this code

```
  MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBeanjobDetail = new MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean();
        Class<?> businessClass = Class.forName(task.getBusinessClassType());
        jobDetail.setTargetObject(applicationContext.getBean(businessClass));
        jobDetail.setTargetMethod(task.getBusinessMethod());
        jobDetail.setName(task.getCode());
        jobDetail.setGroup(task.getGroup().getCode());
        jobDetail.setConcurrent(false);

        Object[] argumentArray = builArgumentArray(task.getBusinessMethodParams());
        jobDetail.setArguments(argumentArray);

        jobDetail.afterPropertiesSet();

        CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(task.getCode() + "_TRIGGER", task.getGroup().getCode() + "_TRIGGER_GROUP")
                      .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(task.getCronExpression())).build();

        dataSchedulazione = scheduler.scheduleJob((JobDetail) jobDetail.getObject(), trigger);
        scheduler.start();
```

sometimes the task stop to respond if i remove the trigger and the task from scheduler 
remain in
`List ob = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();`

The state of the trigger is NONE but is still in scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();

I have tried to implent InterruptableJob in a class that extend MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBeanjobDetail

But when i use

```
scheduler.interrupt(jobKey);
```

It say that the InterruptableJob is not implemented.
I think is because the  instance of the class is MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBeanjobDetail

```
`scheduler.scheduleJob((JobDetail) jobDetail.getObject(), trigger);`
```

this is the code inside the quartz scheduler

```
`job = jec.getJobInstance();
                if (job instanceof InterruptableJob) {
                    ((InterruptableJob)job).interrupt();
                    interrupted = true;
                } else {
                    throw new UnableToInterruptJobException(
                            "Job " + jobDetail.getKey() +
                            " can not be interrupted, since it does not implement " +                        
                            InterruptableJob.class.getName());
                }
`
```

Is there another way to kill a single task?

I use Quartz 2.1.7 and java 1.6 and java 1.8

TIA

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic way to force JVM to stop execution of some piece of code.

You can implement different ways to interrupt the job. But the most appropriate way is to implement *InterruptableJob*.

Implementing this interface is not sufficient. You should implement a job in such way that it really reacts on such requests.

**Example**

Suppose, your job is processing 1 000 000 records in the database or in a file and it take relatively long time, let say 1 hour. Then one possible implementation can be following. In the method "interrupt()" you set some flag (member variable) to "true", let name it *isInterruptionRequested*. In the main logic part that is processing 1 000 000 records you can regularly, e.g. each 5 seconds or after each let say 100 records check if this flag *isInterruptionRequested* is set to "true". If set, you exit from the method where you implemented the main logic.

It is important that you don't check the condition *too often*. Otherwise, depending on the logic, it may happen that checking if the job interruption was requested may take 80-90% of CPU, much more than the actual logic :)

Thus, even when you implement the *InterruptableJob* interface properly, it doesn't mean that the job will be stopped immediately. It will be just a hint like "I would like to stop this job when it is possible". When it will be stopped (if at all) depends on how you implement it.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is to remove orphan task.
Sometimes a task freeze without exception and remain in the scheduler i i'm not be able to kill or interrupt in that case.
I'have tried to implement interruptable interfaced but the job is constructed with Spring MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBeanjobDetail and the result object does not have that interface